# How do you sketch the LHS and RHS on one pair of axes and then solve

Tags: inequality

I understand how to graph $|x-1|$ but unsure how to graph $|x/2-1|$. I don't understand how the coefficient of $x$ affects the graph. I'm also not sure how to find the values of $x$ for when $|x+1| ≥ |x/2 -1|$.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: How do you graph |x-1|?

Comment: When you are dealing with absolute value it could be more easier splitting it. In this case you can write $\displaystyle \begin{cases}y=\frac{x}{2}-1,&x\ge 2\\ y=1-\frac{x}{2},&x<2\end{cases}$. I believe you know how to plot these two lines. In order to solve the inequality you need to understand that if $|a|\ge |b|$, then $a\ge b \vee a\le -b$. Good luck!

Comment: @Galc127: so $|a|\ge |b|$ if $a=-1$ and $b=-5$

Comment: @miracle173, you are correct. Unfortunately I can't edit my comment.